# JS Template Frameworks & Screenreader?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, handlebars.js, mustache

Anyone know how well template frameworks such as Handlebars.js, Underscore.js or Mustache work with screen readers?

Answer (score 1):

Screen readers like [JAWS](http://www.freedomscientific.com/products/fs/jaws-product-page.asp) are usually able to read anything that has been rendered into the browser.

The problem is when dynamically replacing parts of the page because there is not really a way to tell it where to set the cursor. The advantage when using Mustache (Handlebars) is that you can also easily provide a separate, more accessible version of your page (generated server side) without having to recreate all your templates.